How do I reveal the bonus art in the Art Gallery?
After using a key to open the first Concept Art room in the Art Gallery, I noticed some of the pictures were missing, displaying as a blue question mark. If I go to examine them, they are labeled as "bonus art".
How do I reveal these bonus art pieces in the Art Gallery?


Those are the ending screens. And as you can guess you unlock them by getting the corresponding ending.
Since you didn't ask, I won't spoil the ending requirements here, but they should be quite obvious. Just.. think about Metroid.
